# How can I let TextMate show line numbers when I'm coding C++?

Tags: macos, text-editors, textmate, c++

How can I let TextMate show line numbers when I'm coding C++?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Press `Cmd-Opt-L` or select *View » Gutter » Line Numbers*.

I don't think it's possible to automatically enable display of line numbers dependent on your current language. But with the default keyboard shortcut this command is easy enough to reach.

Comment: While I certainly appreciate all the up votes for this answer, I'd like to use the popularity of this question to demonstrate [how convenient it is to find menu items and commands in pretty much any OS X application](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cQjeL.png).

Answer (score 3):

View->Gutter->Line Numbers

Enjoy! Its a fun editor.

Answer (score 0):

For users stumbling on this question who want to actually insert numbers in front of each line, the following will help:

1. Bundles > Text > Add Line Numbers to Selection

   - Applies `"cat -n|expand -8"` to selection/entire document
2. Text -> Filter through command... allows more flexibility. e.g.:

   - `perl -pe 's/^/sprintf("%2d ",$.)/e'`

Thanks to @Hans and @Paul on the [TM list](http://textmate.1073791.n5.nabble.com/How-do-I-insert-a-sequence-of-numbers-to-a-rectangular-selection-td26483.html)