# Set current language without saving file in Sublime Text

Tags: language, sublime-text-2

I have recently started using `Sublime Text 2` after getting tired with `Notepad++`. Now, if I wanted to set what language I am currently programming in in `Notepad++`, I would go to the `Language` menu, and select whichever language I wanted. But in `Sublime`, the only way I have found out how to do that is to save the file in the file format of the language, and then all the colouring and other syntax helpers are loaded. So, is there any way I can change the language I am writing in without saving? If so, how?

This is mainly because I want to play around with test scripts which don't need saving.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Click the *Plain Text* label at the bottom right of the window and select your language.

[image: Plain Text syntax highlighting screenshot]

[image: Java syntax highlighting screenshot]

---

Alternatively, select your language in the menu at *View » Syntax*, or open your command palette (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>) and type `ssjava` (equals to `Set Syntax: Java`).

Comment: FACEPALM! Sorry, I should have noticed that sooner. In my classic working environment at the moment, I have VLC in the bottom right corner of the screen watching whatever tv series has tickled my fancy. Did not see that at all

Comment: @cgoddard If you're on OS X, [there's an easy way to find menu items with certain labels](http://superuser.com/questions/257616/how-can-i-let-textmate-show-line-numbers-when-im-coding-c/257619#comment555753_257619) as well -- in this case, a search for a language name showed me where the language menu items are.

Comment: @cgoddard The command palette can also be easily used to change the syntax; see my update on Daniel's answer.

Comment: Is it possible to set one by default?

Answer (score 0):

In Menu. View -> Sintax. And chose the language that you need like Notepad++